# Не компилируется класс без указания пакета

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Только начинаю учить Java, скачал Intellij IDEA. 
И пробую скомпилировать самый обычную программу.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello world");
  }
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: почему программа не работает без package com.company, в учебнике введения в язык и на видео YouTube не приходилось прописывать данную строчку. Можно сделать, чтобы у меня тоже без нее работало? (Не хочется каждый раз лишний текст вводить, который я пока не понимаю)

Comment: Потому что вы что-то не так делаете в IDE. Программа должна компилироваться без указания пакета.

Comment: Понимаю.. но вроде следовал иструкции установки. Разве нельзя как-то исправить это?

Comment: Чтобы что-то исправить, нужно знать в чём проблема. Повторю, ни язык, ни IDEA не требуют указания пакета.

Comment: Вот код ошибки
`Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.Main`

Comment: "Только начинаю учить Java, скачал Intellij IDEA...." - в этом и есть твоя проблема. Начинаешь учить Java и сразу Intellij IDEA. Что за мода такая пошла - начать учить язык и сразу в IDE. Научитесь хоть что нибудь руками делать....

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. По дефолту, при создании проекта в поле Base package стояло com.company. Не заметил этого. Теперь убрал, все нормально работает. – Jerry08 прямо сейчас

Answer (score 0):

При создании проекта нужно создать пустой Java-проект, и в таком случае сам создашь себе нужные классы и пакеты. В твоем случае ты просто создал Command Lina App, вот он и требует пакет. Убери галочки при создании и все!